# Escribir diccionario en archivo en Python

Tags: python, archivo, diccionarios

Tengo una serie de variables que quiero guardar en un archivo de texto plano del siguiente modo:

```
{'right': None, 'time_right': 0, 'left': None} = None
```

Esas variables se declaran en la función de la clase del siguiente modo:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.right = None       
    self.time_right = 0     
    self.left = None
```

Así que intento escribirla usando `self.__dict__` en la siguiente función:

```
def writeFile(self, file):
    with open(file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(self.__dict__, " = None\n")
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error: `f.write(self.__dict__, " = None\n") TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'`

Sabéis cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` sólo lleva un argumento (la cadena de texto que vas a guardar). Primero obtén la representación en cadena de texto del diccionario (con la función `str`), y luego concaténala con `" = None\n"`:

```
def writeFile(self, file):
    with open(file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(self.__dict__) + " = None\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

Un diccionario no es una cadena. En un fichero de texto sólo puedes volcar cadenas.

La solución obvia es convertir el diccionario en cadena con `str()`, por ejemplo:

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.right = None       
    self.time_right = 0     
    self.left = None   

foo = Foo()
with open("ejemplo.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(foo.__dict__) + " = None")
```

Eso dejará en el fichero el siguiente texto:

```
{'right': None, 'time_right': 0, 'left': None} = None
```

#### Nota

Lo que estás intentando volcar se parece a un JSON. Este se parece mucho a un diccionario Python pero no es exactamente igual. Por ejemplo en el Json la palabra especial `None` de python no es válida, y en su lugar debe usarse `null`. Además las comillas han de ser dobles en vez de simples, y otras diferencias.

Por si esta era tu intención, puedes convertir el diccionario en un json (que no deja de ser otra cadena, pero con un formato diferente) mediante el siguiente código:

```py
import json
foo = Foo()
with open("ejemplo.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(foo.__dict__))
```

y en este caso el texto que aparecerá en el fichero será:

```json
{"right": null, "time_right": 0, "left": null}
```

En este caso no sería JSON válido añadirle el  `= None` final.

La ventaja del JSON es que es más estándar. Es posible leer ese fichero fácilmente desde otros lenguajes (o desde Python). Dependiendo de tu objetivo puede ser más conveniente.